# Elasticsearch query returns 10 when expecting > 10,000

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to retrieve all the JSON objects in `Elasticsearch` that have a `null` value for `awsKafkaTimestamp`. This is the query I have set up:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "tracer.awsKafkaTimestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I curl to my elasticsearch endpoint with the `DSL` I only get a few values back. I am expecting all (10000+) of them because I know for sure all the `awsKafkaTimestamp` values are `null`

This is the response I get when I use `Postman`. As you can see, there are only 10 JSON objects returned to me:

[image]

Comment: You got to specify 'size'

Answer (score 7):

It's correct behaviour of the elasticsearch. By default, it only returns 10 records and provides information in hits.total field about the total number of documents matching search criteria. To retrieve more data than 10 you should specify size field in your query as shown below (you can read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html):

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not get the whole results set, because size parameter is limited to 10000. Beyond this number you should use scroll api. If you set it over 10000 api will return an error related to this.

Answer (score 5):

By default elasticsearch will give you 10 results, even if it matches to `10212`. You can set the size parameter but that is limited to 10000, so your only option is to use the scroll API to get,

Example from elasticsearch site [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: This is a better answer, however I am having trouble with this as I did a POST to my elasticsearch endpoint (`http://{host}:{port}/_search?scroll=1m`) and I got a `_scroll_id` and also 10 hits in return. When I posted to `http://{host}:{port}/_search/scroll`, passing in the object `{"scroll": "1m", "scroll_id": "{scroll_id}"}` I only get 10 hits returned to me